# Position Based Rank in SOLR

Tags: solr, lucene

I need to sort SOLR search results based on position of search query.For example I have 4 documents

1.demo of solr lucene

2.lucene focuses mainly on text indexing

3.explain lucene with example

4.lucene is an open source

when I will search with query text **lucene** then I need result in following order

2.lucene focuses mainly on text indexing

4.lucene is an open source

3.explain lucene with example

1.demo of solr lucene

**i.e. boost search query in first and second position higher than other**

**Following is field defination I have used on which I need position based sort**

```
*<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" catenateNumbers="1" generateNumberParts="1" protected="protwords.txt" splitOnCaseChange="1" generateWordParts="0" preserveOriginal="1" catenateAll="0" catenateWords="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>        
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" catenateNumbers="1" generateNumberParts="1" protected="protwords.txt" splitOnCaseChange="1" generateWordParts="0" preserveOriginal="1" catenateAll="0" catenateWords="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
   <similarity class="CustomSimilarity" />
</fieldType>*
```

for this I have tried to disable termfrequency by adding customSimilarity class in solr but I am getting error as

**Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType : Error loading class**

Following is the class defination for CustomSimilarity classs

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.payloads.PayloadHelper;
import org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.DefaultSimilarity;
import org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.Similarity;
import org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef;
import org.apache.solr.common.params.SolrParams;
import org.apache.solr.schema.SimilarityFactory;
import org.apache.solr.search.similarities.SchemaSimilarityFactory;


public class CustomSimilarity extends SchemaSimilarityFactory{

    public float tf(float freq) {
        return 1.0f;
    }

}
```

And jar file path in solrconfig

```
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/"  regex=".*.jar" />
```

Any help will be appriciated

Comment: You need to paste the class file..  and field definition too..

Comment: @hacker315..... I have generated jar file for the custom class and provided path in solr config and used that class as similarity class in managed schema for the field

Comment: There is some issue in the class definition it seems..

Comment: @hacker315....edited question with class defination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things.

1) You forgot to write @Override, so that your definition of tf is picked up.

2) In specifying jar path, regex has to be ".*.jar"

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.payloads.PayloadHelper;
import org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.DefaultSimilarity;
import org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.Similarity;
import org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef;
import org.apache.solr.common.params.SolrParams;
import org.apache.solr.schema.SimilarityFactory;
import org.apache.solr.search.similarities.SchemaSimilarityFactory;


public class CustomSimilarity extends SchemaSimilarityFactory{

    @Override
    public float tf(float freq) {
        return 1.0f;
    }

}
```

Regex:

```
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/"  regex=".*\.jar" />
```

Comment: `@Override` is only relevant as a decorator that gives an error if there is no method to override; extending the class doesn't require it - it's only an extra failsafe to verify that you're not "overriding" a non-existing method by error. The Solr log should also show the name of all the jar files that are being loaded.

Comment: @hacker315.....actually after changing regex file path previous error resolved but now I am getting another error i.e "SchemaSimilarityFactory can not be used until SolrCoreAware.inform has been called"

Comment: @PujaAlagi Kindly create a new question for it. and tick mark the correct answer, if it helped..