# Adding CustomSimilarity class in solr

Tags: solr, lucene

After adding CustomSimilarity class in solr I am getting following error

```
Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "Custom_field": SchemaSimilarityFactory can not be used until SolrCoreAware.inform has been called
```

even if I have called SolrCoreAware.inform method.

My class defination is as below

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.payloads.PayloadHelper;
import org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.DefaultSimilarity;
import org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.Similarity;
import org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.ClassicSimilarity;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;
import org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef;
import org.apache.solr.common.params.SolrParams;
import org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore;
import org.apache.solr.schema.SimilarityFactory;
import org.apache.solr.search.similarities.SchemaSimilarityFactory;
import org.apache.solr.util.plugin.SolrCoreAware;


public class CustomSimilarity extends SchemaSimilarityFactory implements SolrCoreAware {

    private volatile SolrCore core; 
    private Version coreVersion;

    @Override
    public void inform(SolrCore core) {
            this.core = core;
            this.coreVersion = this.core.getSolrConfig().luceneMatchVersion;
    }

        public float tf(float freq) {
            return 1.0f;
        }
}
```

Any help will be appriciated..

Comment: I don't think you want to extend `SchemaSimilarityFactory` (since that's a wrapper class that allows you to specify similarity per field and in the schema), but instead extend the `SimilarityFactory` as the other similarity implementations do? See https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/5affe7421f3f927e1fcfb7c7cb763179ce686997/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/search/similarities/DFRSimilarityFactory.java for example - and the ClassicSimilarity (which you might want to extend instead) in the same directory.

Comment: @MatsLindh....thanks for the reply ....when I extend ClassicSimilarity instead of SchemaSimilarityFactory class there is no effect in ranking in solr...actually I need to sort my solr result as I have mentioned in question...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61931729/position-based-rank-in-solr  instead of CustomSimilaruty class if you have any other solution please help

Comment: Have you actually configured Solr to use your custom similarity class? You have to configure it as well - and you can then look at debug output (`debug=all`) to see the score contributed by your similarity. It's not enough to just extend the class and include the jar.

Comment: @MatsLindh...Yes configured in field for which I want to omit termfrequency as :    <similarity class="CustomSimilarity" /> 
Apart from this anything else I need to do

Comment: Then the debug output should tell you what's being returned for the score for the field, and the Solr log should show your jar being loaded when starting up